# OAuth - does it make sense to combine Device Flow and Client Credentials flows on same client?

Tags: oauth-2.0, identityserver4

I am developing a browserless app that needs access to two APIs - an Application API (read-only, e.g remote configuration) and a User API (read-write, e.g user preferences).

The app has the Client ID and Secret stored locally and therefore takes advantage of the Client Credentials flow to access the Application API.
Now I need users to be able to access a User API and I'm wondering how to configure the backend (which in this case uses IdentityServer4) to do so. The API should be protected so that only authenticated users can access it and am planning on reading the Claims sent to identify the user.

Should I extend the existing Client ID to also allow the Device Flow grant type or create a separate Client just for this "user-only" flow?

I'm new to OAuth and want to make sure I'm doing this right so everything is kept secure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always use different OAuth clients for different client side connections, which will give you more control:

- Rules such as access token lifetime can be set differently when needed
- A compromised client (eg secret stolen) can be disabled without impacting other clients
- Metrics and logging will be more useful also

It is usually easy to easily configure multiple clients in the Authorization Server via a Management UI.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you. I must admit that having 1 application made me question the need for more "clients" when it's essentially the same one, just different use cases.

Comment: Another option might be a single client with different scopes, though personally I would keep them separate. Sounds like you need to write code for 2 flows and use 2 types of token, whichever option you choose. If possible I would aim to make the remote configuration download contain only public info so that it doesn't need securing, so that you only need the device flow option.

Comment: As an example a Web UI of mine downloads these [config details](https://web.authsamples.com/spa/spa.config.json) and it wouldn't bother me if a hacker got hold of them.

Comment: Agreed. The remote config was just an example, in my case the application will need to read more than that but the security aspect is exactly why I'm keeping things read-only and won't have sensitive data on those endpoints. If something happens to the keys at the very least the attacker can't destroy anything until they're rotated...!